# Node + mongoose: delete all records from a model and its relations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a Node app there is a model called *Version* which has a reference to an array of a Resource model thourgh its *id* (as an *one to many* relation):

```
const versionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  images: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Resource' }]
}, { timestamps: true })
const Version = mongoose.model('version', versionSchema)
```

In some part of the application I want to remove all the 'versions' and those resources related to them. I have wroted the coded below, it works, but I don´t know (and I can't find out) if this is the best way.

```
const versions = await Version.find()
for(let version of versions) {
  const ids = version.images
  await Resource.remove({_id: {$in: ids }})
  await version.delete()
}
```

Can anyone help me, telling me if this is a good approach or if there is another way that is more suitable fot what I have to do?

Comment: Cannot you add a middleware in the version model to delete each resource before removing all the version?

Comment: if it satisfies the use case. Also to avoid the delete call loop of the version we can collect the ids and remove all the resources in one db call.